# How to make a vertical \iff?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I will like to make a vertical version of `\iff`. I can not be satisfied with `\Updownarrow`, as it is too short.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\Updownarrow` is an extensible symbol, so you can use `\Big` in front of it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Longupdownarrow}{\Big\Updownarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a+b&=c \\
\Longupdownarrow \\
x+y&=z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is the simplest way. 
The example you have written is actually have I want to use it!  Bravo

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with a `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\[ A\mathrel{\mkern 3mu\rotatebox[origin =c]{90}{$\iff$}}B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: as suggested by @egreg, you might consider using `\Longleftrightarrow`, which has a different spacing  on each side (i.e. above and below after rotation):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*} 
    xxx yyyy zzz \\
A\mathrel{\mkern 3mu\rotatebox[origin =c]{90}{$\iff$}}B \\
 xxx yyyy zzz \\
 A\mathrel{\mkern 3mu\rotatebox[origin =c]{90}{$\Longleftrightarrow$}}B \\
    xxx yyyy zzz%
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `\Longrightarrow` is better than `\iff`, which adds spaces on either side (so above and below when rotated).